# RcppArmadillo: Error when installing package on Mac

Tags: r, rcpp

I have an R package which I am trying to install on a MAC OS (yosemite), and I am getting a linker problem. This is the error that I am getting

```
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o File1.so File2.o File3.o File4.o RcppExports.o Utils.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mypackage.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mypackage’
```

My `Makevars` file contain:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

In `DESCRIPTION`, I have:

```
Depends:
    R (>= 3.2.0),
    Rcpp,
    RcppArmadillo
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
```

and in `R/help.R`, I have:

```
#' @importFrom Rcpp evalCpp
#' @import RcppArmadillo
#' @useDynLib mypackage
NULL
```

This is not the same issue as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767816/rcpp-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lgfortran) because I already included the Armadillo dependencies in the header file that is being indluced by the other `.cpp` files:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <Rmath.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
```

Am I missing something? Should the makefile be modified?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rcpp error: /usr/bin/ld cannot find -lgfortran](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767816/rcpp-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lgfortran)

Comment: @nrussel I don't think so, I already have the RcppArmadillo dependency included.

Comment: IIRC when I had a similar issue I solved it by installing gfortran from research.att, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25912049/471093

Comment: Please see the Rcpp FAQ on this. I was recently updated and expanded.

Comment: @Cauchy No I was referring to the `ld: library not found for -lgfortran` error. From the FAQ, *"While gfortran is distributed as part of gcc and hence is available by default on most Linux distributions, it is not
distributed as part of Apple’s command line tools.  So, unfortunately, you’re going to need to install gfortran and its associated libraries yourself."*

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I will. Is it wrong to put `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]` in a header file and not a .cpp file?

Comment: You don't compile headers, only source files ie `.cpp`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixes:

**Easy fix**

Open the `Terminal` from `/Applications/Utilities/`

Type the following into `Terminal`

```
curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2
sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /
```

**More time consuming:**

Use `homebrew` or `macports` to grab `gcc` which contains `gfortran`. Change the `~/.R/Makevars`. (See the openmp post for more details on the gfortran install with `homebrew`.)

See:

1. http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-os-x/
2. http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error/
3. http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/
4. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf#page=8